# Path confusion using Conda, PIP, and Jupyter notebook at the same time

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, conda, pydicom

I've been using conda and jupyter notebook for a while now and recently I need some packages that are only available for install via pip. My understanding was that they are completely compatible and transparent with each other but apparently not.

I did a `pip install pydicom` and when I tried to do an `import pydicom` in my Jupyter Notebook, it says `No module named pydicom`.

In command prompt (using a Windows machine here) I ran `conda list` and I see `pydicom` is listed and marked as < pip >.

In my Jupyter notebook, this is my `sys.executable` output:

> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\python.exe

Is that normal/correct???

Disclaimer: I'm thoroughly confused by how the paths, environment, and dependencies work in conda and pip. I can't find a good tutorial or explanation how conda/pip work behind the scenes. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the package is named pydicom, you need to import `dicom`:

```
import dicom
```

You can also in install `pydicom` via `conda`. You need to provide the channel 'conda-forge`:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pydicom
```

You can find more packages a https://anaconda.org/. Just enter the package name in the search window. If the package is available you will see the channel you can with the `-c` option.

Comment: Thanks Muke Muller! For future reference, can you give me some tips as to finding a conda equivalent?